# JSF EAR deployment issue on JBOSS - class not found

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jboss

I am migrating an application from Websphere to JBOSS EAP 6.1. When I try and deploy, I get the following error:-

```
12:57:49,271 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC000001:      Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."BordereauxPortal2EAR_test_8May_v2.ear"."BordereauxPortal.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."BordereauxPortal2EAR_test_8May_v2.ear"."BordereauxPortal.war".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment "BordereauxPortal.war" of deployment "BordereauxPortal2EAR_test_8May_v2.ear"
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:127) [jboss-as-server-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/component/UIComponent
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at org.jboss.as.jsf.deployment.JSFManagedBeanProcessor.deploy(JSFManagedBeanProcessor.java:103)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:120) [jboss-as-server-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.component.UIComponent from [Module "deployment.BordereauxPortal2EAR_test_8May_v2.ear:main" from Service Module Loader]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:196) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:444) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:432) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:374) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:119) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
... 11 more
```

Now I suspect that this is a badly constructed app and that it references the UIComponent in way that it shouldn't and the classpath is thus not right to find the class? Any advice on where to start looking to find out more info much appreciated!

Some more details after coment:-
I am using JBOSS EAP 6.1

The configuration file is standard (out of the box) as follows:-

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:1.4">
<extensions>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.cmp"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.connector"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.deployment-scanner"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.ee"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.ejb3"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.jacorb"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.jaxr"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.jaxrs"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.jdr"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.jmx"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.jpa"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.jsf"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.jsr77"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.logging"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.mail"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.messaging"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.naming"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.pojo"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.remoting"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.sar"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.security"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.threads"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.transactions"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.web"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.webservices"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.weld"/>
</extensions>
<management>
    <security-realms>
        <security-realm name="ManagementRealm">
            <authentication>
                <local default-user="$local"/>
                <properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
            </authentication>
        </security-realm>
        <security-realm name="ApplicationRealm">
            <authentication>
                <local default-user="$local" allowed-users="*"/>
                <properties path="application-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
            </authentication>
            <authorization>
                <properties path="application-roles.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
            </authorization>
        </security-realm>
    </security-realms>
    <management-interfaces>
        <native-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">
            <socket-binding native="management-native"/>
        </native-interface>
        <http-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">
            <socket-binding http="management-http"/>
        </http-interface>
    </management-interfaces>
</management>
<profile>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.2">
        <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <formatter>
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
            </formatter>
        </console-handler>
        <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
            <formatter>
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
            </formatter>
            <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
            <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
            <append value="true"/>
        </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
        <logger category="com.arjuna">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="sun.rmi">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="jacorb">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="jacorb.config">
            <level name="ERROR"/>
        </logger>
        <root-logger>
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                <handler name="FILE"/>
            </handlers>
        </root-logger>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:cmp:1.1"/>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.1">
        <datasources>
            <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</connection-url>
                <driver>h2</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>sa</user-name>
                    <password>sa</password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                    <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
        </datasources>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:1.1">
        <deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-interval="5000"/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.1">
        <spec-descriptor-property-replacement>false</spec-descriptor-property-replacement>
        <jboss-descriptor-property-replacement>true</jboss-descriptor-property-replacement>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:1.4">
        <session-bean>
            <stateless>
                <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="slsb-strict-max-pool"/>
            </stateless>
            <stateful default-access-timeout="5000" cache-ref="simple"/>
            <singleton default-access-timeout="5000"/>
        </session-bean>
        <mdb>
            <resource-adapter-ref resource-adapter-name="hornetq-ra"/>
            <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="mdb-strict-max-pool"/>
        </mdb>
        <pools>
            <bean-instance-pools>
                <strict-max-pool name="slsb-strict-max-pool" max-pool-size="20" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
                <strict-max-pool name="mdb-strict-max-pool" max-pool-size="20" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
            </bean-instance-pools>
        </pools>
        <caches>
            <cache name="simple" aliases="NoPassivationCache"/>
            <cache name="passivating" passivation-store-ref="file" aliases="SimpleStatefulCache"/>
        </caches>
        <passivation-stores>
            <file-passivation-store name="file"/>
        </passivation-stores>
        <async thread-pool-name="default"/>
        <timer-service thread-pool-name="default">
            <data-store path="timer-service-data" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/>
        </timer-service>
        <remote connector-ref="remoting-connector" thread-pool-name="default"/>
        <thread-pools>
            <thread-pool name="default">
                <max-threads count="10"/>
                <keepalive-time time="100" unit="milliseconds"/>
            </thread-pool>
        </thread-pools>
        <iiop enable-by-default="false" use-qualified-name="false"/>
        <default-security-domain value="other"/>
        <default-missing-method-permissions-deny-access value="true"/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:1.4">
        <cache-container name="web" aliases="standard-session-cache" default-cache="local-web" module="org.jboss.as.clustering.web.infinispan">
            <local-cache name="local-web" batching="true">
                <file-store passivation="false" purge="false"/>
            </local-cache>
        </cache-container>
        <cache-container name="hibernate" default-cache="local-query" module="org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate:4">
            <local-cache name="entity">
                <transaction mode="NON_XA"/>
                <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
            </local-cache>
            <local-cache name="local-query">
                <transaction mode="NONE"/>
                <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
            </local-cache>
            <local-cache name="timestamps">
                <transaction mode="NONE"/>
                <eviction strategy="NONE"/>
            </local-cache>
        </cache-container>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jacorb:1.3">
        <orb socket-binding="jacorb" ssl-socket-binding="jacorb-ssl">
            <initializers transactions="spec" security="identity"/>
        </orb>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jaxr:1.1">
        <connection-factory jndi-name="java:jboss/jaxr/ConnectionFactory"/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jaxrs:1.0"/>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jca:1.1">
        <archive-validation enabled="true" fail-on-error="true" fail-on-warn="false"/>
        <bean-validation enabled="true"/>
        <default-workmanager>
            <short-running-threads>
                <core-threads count="50"/>
                <queue-length count="50"/>
                <max-threads count="50"/>
                <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
            </short-running-threads>
            <long-running-threads>
                <core-threads count="50"/>
                <queue-length count="50"/>
                <max-threads count="50"/>
                <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
            </long-running-threads>
        </default-workmanager>
        <cached-connection-manager/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jdr:1.0"/>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.2">
        <expose-resolved-model/>
        <expose-expression-model/>
        <remoting-connector/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jpa:1.1">
        <jpa default-datasource="" default-extended-persistence-inheritance="DEEP"/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jsf:1.0"/>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jsr77:1.0"/>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:mail:1.1">
        <mail-session jndi-name="java:jboss/mail/Default">
            <smtp-server outbound-socket-binding-ref="mail-smtp"/>
        </mail-session>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging:1.3">
        <hornetq-server>
            <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>
            <journal-type>NIO</journal-type>
            <journal-min-files>2</journal-min-files>
            <connectors>
                <netty-connector name="netty" socket-binding="messaging"/>
                <netty-connector name="netty-throughput" socket-binding="messaging-throughput">
                    <param key="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                </netty-connector>
                <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
            </connectors>
            <acceptors>
                <netty-acceptor name="netty" socket-binding="messaging"/>
                <netty-acceptor name="netty-throughput" socket-binding="messaging-throughput">
                    <param key="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                    <param key="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
                </netty-acceptor>
                <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
            </acceptors>
            <security-settings>
                <security-setting match="#">
                    <permission type="send" roles="guest"/>
                    <permission type="consume" roles="guest"/>
                    <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
                    <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
                </security-setting>
            </security-settings>
            <address-settings>
                <!--default for catch all-->
                <address-setting match="#">
                    <dead-letter-address>jms.queue.DLQ</dead-letter-address>
                    <expiry-address>jms.queue.ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
                    <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
                    <max-size-bytes>10485760</max-size-bytes>
                    <address-full-policy>BLOCK</address-full-policy>
                    <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
                </address-setting>
            </address-settings>
            <jms-connection-factories>
                <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory">
                    <connectors>
                        <connector-ref connector-name="in-vm"/>
                    </connectors>
                    <entries>
                        <entry name="java:/ConnectionFactory"/>
                    </entries>
                </connection-factory>
                <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory">
                    <connectors>
                        <connector-ref connector-name="netty"/>
                    </connectors>
                    <entries>
                        <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory"/>
                    </entries>
                </connection-factory>
                <pooled-connection-factory name="hornetq-ra">
                    <transaction mode="xa"/>
                    <connectors>
                        <connector-ref connector-name="in-vm"/>
                    </connectors>
                    <entries>
                        <entry name="java:/JmsXA"/>
                    </entries>
                </pooled-connection-factory>
            </jms-connection-factories>
        </hornetq-server>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:1.3">
        <remote-naming/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:pojo:1.0"/>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:remoting:1.1">
        <connector name="remoting-connector" socket-binding="remoting" security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:1.1"/>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:sar:1.0"/>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.2">
        <security-domains>
            <security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">
                <authentication>
                    <login-module code="Remoting" flag="optional">
                        <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                    </login-module>
                    <login-module code="RealmDirect" flag="required">
                        <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                    </login-module>
                </authentication>
            </security-domain>
            <security-domain name="jboss-web-policy" cache-type="default">
                <authorization>
                    <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                </authorization>
            </security-domain>
            <security-domain name="jboss-ejb-policy" cache-type="default">
                <authorization>
                    <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                </authorization>
            </security-domain>
        </security-domains>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:threads:1.1"/>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:transactions:1.3">
        <core-environment>
            <process-id>
                <uuid/>
            </process-id>
        </core-environment>
        <recovery-environment socket-binding="txn-recovery-environment" status-socket-binding="txn-status-manager"/>
        <coordinator-environment default-timeout="300"/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.4" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
        <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
        <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
            <alias name="localhost"/>
            <alias name="example.com"/>
        </virtual-server>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:webservices:1.2">
        <modify-wsdl-address>true</modify-wsdl-address>
        <wsdl-host>${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}</wsdl-host>
        <endpoint-config name="Standard-Endpoint-Config"/>
        <endpoint-config name="Recording-Endpoint-Config">
            <pre-handler-chain name="recording-handlers" protocol-bindings="##SOAP11_HTTP ##SOAP11_HTTP_MTOM ##SOAP12_HTTP ##SOAP12_HTTP_MTOM">
                <handler name="RecordingHandler" class="org.jboss.ws.common.invocation.RecordingServerHandler"/>
            </pre-handler-chain>
        </endpoint-config>
        <client-config name="Standard-Client-Config"/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:weld:1.0"/>
</profile>
<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
    <!-- TODO - only show this if the jacorb subsystem is added  -->
    <interface name="unsecure">
        <!--
          ~  Used for IIOP sockets in the standard configuration.
          ~                  To secure JacORB you need to setup SSL 
          -->
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
    <socket-binding name="management-native" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.native.port:9999}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9443}"/>
    <socket-binding name="ajp" port="8009"/>
    <socket-binding name="http" port="8080"/>
    <socket-binding name="https" port="8443"/>
    <socket-binding name="jacorb" interface="unsecure" port="3528"/>
    <socket-binding name="jacorb-ssl" interface="unsecure" port="3529"/>
    <socket-binding name="messaging" port="5445"/>
    <socket-binding name="messaging-group" port="0" multicast-address="${jboss.messaging.group.address:231.7.7.7}" multicast-port="${jboss.messaging.group.port:9876}"/>
    <socket-binding name="messaging-throughput" port="5455"/>
    <socket-binding name="remoting" port="4447"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
    <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
        <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
    </outbound-socket-binding>
</socket-binding-group>
</server>
```

Comment: What version of JBoss are you using?  Do you have the jsf subsystem enabled in your configuration xml?

Comment: have added some additional info

Comment: You may need to create an explicit dependency on jsf.  Have you read this: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/How+do+I+migrate+my+application+from+WebSphere+to+AS+7?  Specifically, look at the sub-section titled jboss-deployment-structure.xml that talks about adding a dependency on jsf.

Comment: Thanks @jgitter, I have added an answer below. My assumptions of what was added automatically was not correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved this - it was my misunderstanding of JBOSS 7 - thanks to @jgitter for help.

I had assumed JSF support was being added but found that adding this to the jboss-deployment-structure.xml file allowed it to be deployed OK. Still not sure if its needed in both places.

```
<deployment> 
<dependencies>
 <module name="javax.faces.api" slot="main"/>
  <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" slot="main"/>
</dependencies>
</deployment>
<sub-deployment name="myWebApp.war">
<dependencies>
 <module name="javax.faces.api" slot="main"/>
  <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" slot="main"/>
</dependencies> 
</sub-deployment>
```

Comment: Nice work chasing that down.  This page may also help you.  It lays out exactly what is required for an implicit dependency inclusion.  https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/Implicit+module+dependencies+for+deployments